# Display an image from a woocoomerce product on a different page and have it update when the variations are edited by user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm stuck trying to get my site together in time for our launch.
We've got a wordpress plugin that displays a product based on selected inputs. Each variation has an image which is layered over top of each other and in pNG to create a final picture. It all works well on the product page http://tattersfield.co/online-tailor-store/double-breasted/luciano-79000-1-jacket/ but now I need the image to display in our Composite Product area http://tattersfield.co/online-tailor-store/three-piece-single-breasted-suit/test-3-piece-suit .
This is the code I need to update to display the plugin generated image instead of the product thumbnail.

```html
<?php
/**
 * Composited Product Image
 * @version  3.0.0
 */

// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )
 exit;

if ( has_post_thumbnail( $product_id ) ) {

 ?><div class="composited_product_images"><?php

   $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_id ) ) );
   $image_link  = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_id ) );
   $image       = get_the_post_thumbnail( $product_id, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_composited_product_thumbnail_size', 'shop_catalog' ), array(
    'title' => $image_title
   ) );

   echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_composited_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="composited_product_image zoom" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $product_id );

 ?></div><?php
}
```

And this is a snippet of the code from the plugin that displays the image. What do I need to do to get these 2 pieces to work together to display the image I'm after?

```html
 Frontend Single Product Page 
    ============================= */
    
    public function display_product_image() {
        
        global $post, $jckpc_options;
     
        $setImages = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $this->slug.'_images', true );
        $defaults = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $this->slug.'_defaults', true );
        $querySelectors = $_GET;
     
        if(!empty($querySelectors)) {
         
            $sanitisedQuerySelectors = array();
        
            foreach($querySelectors as $attSlug => $attVal) {
                $sanitisedQuerySelectors[$this->sanitise_str($attSlug)] = $this->sanitise_str($attVal);
            }
        
            $querySelectors = $sanitisedQuerySelectors;
            
        }
     
        $images = array();
     
        if( $setImages['background'] && $setImages['background'] != '' ) {
            
            $imgSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($setImages['background'], apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ));
            $images[] = '<img id="'.$this->slug.'_image_background" src="'.$imgSrc[0].'">';
        
        }
     
        $setImages = array_reverse($setImages);
        
        $img_i = 1; foreach($setImages as $attSlug => $attVals) {
            
            $default = ( isset($defaults[$attSlug]) && isset($setImages[$attSlug][$defaults[$attSlug]]) ) ? $setImages[$attSlug][$defaults[$attSlug]] : false;
            
            $default = ( isset($querySelectors[$attSlug]) && isset($setImages[$attSlug][$querySelectors[$attSlug]]) ) ? $setImages[$attSlug][$querySelectors[$attSlug]] : $default;
            
            $images[$img_i] = '<div id="'.$this->slug.'_image_'.$attSlug.'">';
            
            if($default) {
                
                $imgSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($default, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ));
                $images[$img_i] .= '<img src="'.$imgSrc[0].'">';
            
            }
            
            $images[$img_i] .= '</div>';
        
            $img_i++; 
        
        }
     
        // output images
        
        echo '<style>';
        
            echo '#jckpc_images {';
                // width
                echo "width: {$jckpc_options['image_container_width']['width']};";
                // align
                if($jckpc_options['image_container_align'] == "centre") {
                    
                    echo "margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;";
                    $jckpc_options['image_container_align'] = "none"; 
                    
                }
                echo "float: {$jckpc_options['image_container_align']};";
                // spacing
                echo "margin-top: {$jckpc_options['image_container_margin']['margin-top']};";
                echo "margin-right: {$jckpc_options['image_container_margin']['margin-right']};";
                echo "margin-bottom: {$jckpc_options['image_container_margin']['margin-bottom']};";
                echo "margin-left: {$jckpc_options['image_container_margin']['margin-left']};";
                // padding
                echo "padding-top: {$jckpc_options['image_container_padding']['padding-top']};";
                echo "padding-right: {$jckpc_options['image_container_padding']['padding-right']};";
                echo "padding-bottom: {$jckpc_options['image_container_padding']['padding-bottom']};";
                echo "padding-left: {$jckpc_options['image_container_padding']['padding-left']};";
                // background
                echo "background: {$jckpc_options['image_container_background']};";
            echo '}';
      
            $horThumbSpacing = $jckpc_options['thumb_spacing']/2;
            $verThumbSpacing = $jckpc_options['thumb_spacing'];
       
            echo "#jckpc_thumbnails {";
                echo "margin: {$verThumbSpacing}px -{$horThumbSpacing}px -{$verThumbSpacing}px;";
            echo "}";
      
            echo '#jckpc_thumbnails a {';
                echo "float: left;";
                echo "display: inline;";
                $thumbWidth = 100/(int)$jckpc_options['thumb_cols_rows'];
                echo "width: {$thumbWidth}%;";
                // spacing
                echo "padding: 0 {$horThumbSpacing}px {$verThumbSpacing}px;";
            echo '}';
      
            echo "#jckpc_image_wrap #jckpc_loading {";
                // background
                echo "background: {$jckpc_options['loading_overlay_colour']};";
            echo "}";
      
            echo "#jckpc_image_wrap #jckpc_loading i {";            
                $loadingIconMTop = 20/2;                
                echo "font-size: 20px;";
                echo "line-height: 20px;";
                echo "margin-top: -{$loadingIconMTop}px;";
                echo "color: {$jckpc_options['loading_icon_colour']};";
            echo "}";
      
            // breakpoint
            if($jckpc_options['enable_breakpoint']) {
                
                echo "@media (max-width: {$jckpc_options['breakpoint']['width']}) {";
                    echo '#jckpc_images {';
                    
                        // width
                        echo "width: {$jckpc_options['image_container_width_breakpoint']['width']};";
                        
                        // align
                        if($jckpc_options['image_container_align_breakpoint'] == "centre") {
                            
                            echo "margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;";
                            $jckpc_options['image_container_align_breakpoint'] = "none";
                        
                        }
                        
                        echo "float: {$jckpc_options['image_container_align_breakpoint']};";
                        
                        // spacing
                        echo "margin-top: {$jckpc_options['image_container_margin_breakpoint']['margin-top']};";
                        echo "margin-right: {$jckpc_options['image_container_margin_breakpoint']['margin-right']};";
                        echo "margin-bottom: {$jckpc_options['image_container_margin_breakpoint']['margin-bottom']};";
                        echo "margin-left: {$jckpc_options['image_container_margin_breakpoint']['margin-left']};";
                        
                    echo "}";
                echo "}";
            
            }
            
        echo '</style>';
     
        echo '<div id="'.$this->slug.'_images">';
        
            echo '<div id="'.$this->slug.'_image_wrap" data-loading="0">';
            
                foreach($images as $image) {
                    
                    echo $image;
                
                }
                
                echo '<div id="'.$this->slug.'_loading"><i class="jckpc-icn-'.$jckpc_options['loading_icon'].' animate-spin"></i></div>';      
            
            echo '</div>';
            
            if($jckpc_options['show_thumbs']) $this->get_thumbnails();
        
        echo '</div>';
     
    }
    
    public function get_thumbnails() {
        
        global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

  $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
  
  if ( $attachment_ids ) {
   
   echo '<div id="'.$this->slug.'_thumbnails">';
  
    $loop = 0;
    $columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 3 );
  
    foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
  
     $classes = array( 'zoom' );
  
     if ( $loop == 0 || $loop % $columns == 0 )
      $classes[] = 'first';
  
     if ( ( $loop + 1 ) % $columns == 0 )
      $classes[] = 'last';
  
     $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
  
     if ( ! $image_link )
      continue;
  
     $image       = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail' ) );
     $image_class = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $classes ) );
     $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );
  
     echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="%s" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_class, $image_title, $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );
  
     $loop++;
    }
  
   echo '</div>';
  }
    }
    
    public function get_image_data($pid, $atts) {
        
        $imgData = array(
            'prodid' => $pid
        );
        
        if(!empty($atts)){
            
            foreach($atts as $attSlug => $attVal) {
             
             if(substr($attSlug, 0, 10) != "attribute_") $attSlug = 'attribute_'.$attSlug;
             $imgData[$attSlug] = sanitize_title_with_dashes($attVal);
             
            }
            
        }
```